How to save Wordpress post and attachment images from front end using media library?
I'm developing a wordpress page to submit a post and its images attachment. I don't use input type="file" instead use jQuery wordpress media library.
  frame.on("select", function () {

  var attachments = frame
    .state()
    .get("selection")
    .map(function (attachment) {
      attachment.toJSON();
      return attachment;
    });

  for (i = 0; i < attachments.length; ++i) {
    //sample function 1: add image preview
    imgContainer.after(
      '<div class="jrl-image-preview"><img src="' +
        attachments[i].attributes.url +
        '" ></div>'
    );

    //sample function 2: add hidden input for each image
    imgContainer.after(
      '<input id="jrl-image-input' +
        attachments[i].id +
        '" type="hidden" name="jrl_attachment_id_array[]"  value="' +
        attachments[i].id +
        '">'
    );
  }

But I don't know how to save the image files into wordpress DB and upload folder.
I tried using $_FILES to get uploaded files but its empty array.
Thanks in advance

edit your question to show us the javascript code you use to send files.

That's all javascript code I have to open media library and preview the images. There's no code to send files. I am developing a form in front end to create a post with its attachment images.

if you use media library, it uploads the file and then you juste have to save the image id. look this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388224/how-to-use-media-library#answer-388258

Thanks but I don't see a script to save the images. As you can see in the script above it can preview selected multiple images (with its hidden value) from media library but when I click on Submit button there is no value in $_FILES. I once using <input type="file" ... and there is value in $_FILES but I prefer use wp media library rather than the html tag.

as I said, it's the media library which do the upload operations. then it returns the identifier of the file and you just have to manage this identifier in your php code.

ok, which wordpress function can be used to save the image files?
